# how to bind an Enum class using linq

Tags: c#

Hey guys im not sure if what i want to do is right or not,
i have diffrent status in our network,which i have created a ENUM class for it:

```
 public enum   AllMachinesStatus
{
    STOP,
    START,
    LINKDOWN,
    ERROR,
    LINK_UP,
    IDLE,

}
```

in database i there is a service which binds these fields,they are all int,the show the number of the machine in each status which should vary from time to time,,now i want to get this data with linq and bind my class,do you think its a right way?or i should create a normal class with a constructor which whenever i call the class i can have the data?

```
var rslt=(from s in db.Machines
          select new AllMachinesStatus{

             //here i dont have access to the properties of enum class to bind them with Count()
                                 }
```

Comment: please show what `s` is here.

Comment: s points to diffrent properties but in my case s.status,status shows the RUN,LINKDOWN,.and also has numberOfmachines field in the db which shows how many RUN,...

Answer (score 0):

If `s` in an integer with a valid value for `AllMachinesStatus`, try:

```
from s in db.Machines select (AllMachinesStatus)s
```

Basically, it is casting the `int` to `AllMachinesStatus` enum

Comment: it does if the field name in the database is exactly the same as the field in my enum right?considering upper case and under score?

Comment: I suppose the value in the database is of `int` type. So `STOP` would equal to 0, `START` to 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is improper usage of `enum` here.

`enum` does not have a constructor, it is a strong type that has an implicit value type, but it is mostly suitable for signaling and flagging.

In this method, you would evaluate on `s` and either cast the correlating `int` value of `s` or a field\property of `s` to `AllMachinesStatus` or do `Enum.Parse` using `s` or a field\property of `s` (i.e. `s.Status`).

---

note that `AllMachinesStatus` `enum` has implicit `int` values.

```cs
public enum AllMachinesStatus
{
    STOP,         // 0
    START,        // 1
    LINKDOWN,     // 2
    ERROR,        // 3
    LINK_UP,      // 4
    IDLE,         // 5
}
```

Example of `Enum.Parse` with `s.Status`

```cs
// note that 'false' is being passed for case insensitive behavior in the method
var rslt=(from s in db.Machines
          select (AllMachinesStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(AllMachinesStatus), s.Status, false));
```

---

### Alternatively,

if `s` had a field (I'll call `BitFlag` for purpose of example) correlating to the `int` value, you could us the following:

Example of casting `int` to `AllMachinesStatus`

```cs
var rslt=(from s in db.Machines
          select (AllMachinesStatus)s.BitFlag);
```

---

Doc References:

- [MSDN System.Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum)
- [MSDN Enum.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse)

---

### EDIT1:

Include examples and corrected sentiment of using `Enum.GetName` to `Enum.Parse`

### EDIT2:

update `s` to use question comment referenced `s.Status` existence.

Comment: If the value is being stored as an integer, cast the value to the appropriate enum. If the value is being stored as a string (name of the enum) then use a value type converter to convert the enum name into the enum type.

Comment: it's also common to bitfield flag enums so that you can represent more than 1 'state'.  when you add `[Flag]` attribute to an `enum`, the implicit int value assignment iterates by bit shifting (powers of 2) `1 << 0` = `1`, `1 << 1` = `2`,  `1 << 2` = `4`, `1 << 3` = `8`.. I believe there is a convention for `0`, it's `NotSet = 0`